# How to store associative array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, and I want to store this array in DB.

This is the php code of my array:

```php
$socialNetwork = array();
$socialNetwork[0]["name"]= "Facebook";
$socialNetwork[0]["account"]= "facebook_account";
$socialNetwork[1]["name"]= "Twitter";
$socialNetwork[1]["account"]= "twitter_account";
$socialNetwork[2]["name"]= "Instagram";
$socialNetwork[2]["account"]= "insta_account";
```

The `var_dump()` looks like this:

```php
array(3) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["name"] => string(8) "Facebook"
    ["account"] => string(16) "facebook_account"
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    ["name"] => string(7) "Twitter"
    ["account"] => string(15) "twitter_account"
  }
  [2] => array(2) {
    ["name"] => string(9) "Instagram"
    ["account"] => string(13) "insta_account"
  }
}
```

I've tried several things but I can't get it to work!

Please help with the code. The table name is **socialAccounts**

Comment: try to use serialize function to store it as is

Answer (score 4):

Add a column in your database for this field; a JSON or TEXT type will do the job.

Next, you should add the column to the `$casts` array on your `SocialAccount` model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'facebook_account' => 'array',
];
```

Now, whenever you retrieve this value, it will be deserialized for you.

To store the value, just use `json_encode()`:

```
$social_account->facebook_account = json_encode($facebookArrayData);
$social_account->save();
```

You can read more on attribute casting in the docs; https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: It's a helpul answer. Thank you!. I'd like to clarify one thing... What is this $facebookArrayData variable??? and where does it come from?